# CSS transitions on universal selector and pseudo elements

Tags: css

I was quickly prototyping an animated header for a website and found a very strange thing: When you apply CSS transitions on the universal selector (`*`), Safari (9) and Chrome (46) will somehow delay animations on pseudo elements (like they are chained). Firefox (41) will not.

Test yourself: https://jsfiddle.net/w0uwkw99/

I'm aware that this is not good practice but I'ld like to know why this happens and what should be the correct behaviour.

Comment: I don't believe it has as much to do with the universal selector as it does the hierarchic levels of elements, adjacent siblings will transition at the same rate, decedents seem to take on a delay. https://jsfiddle.net/darcher/w0uwkw99/1/

Comment: @darcher: It's actually about animating `inherit`.

Comment: @SLaks That makes sense, and why only the decedents would be affected.

Answer (score 3):

This actually has nothing to do with pseudo-elements, nor the universal selector.

The problem is that `inherit` and transitions don't play well in WebKit.  It will only propagate the value to the `inherit`ed elements after the parent animation finishes.

If you explicitly apply the color to the pseudo-elements and nested elements, the animation will work correctly.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/SLaks/w0uwkw99/3/)

Comment: @achairapart: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-delay